# Error: mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fstab, ftp

When I try to give access to the same target directory to multiple FTP users using these commands:

```
sudo mount --bind /home/max/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand
sudo mount --bind /home/r1ven/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand/etc/fstab
```

/etc/fstab

```
/home/r1ven/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand none bind 0 0
/home/max/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand none bind 0 0
```

An error in /var/log/syslog

```
Dec 12 18:32:31 riven kernel: [    2.131397] systemd-fstab-generator[292]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/home-riven-Desktop-ExLand.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
Dec 12 18:32:31 riven kernel: [    2.131711] systemd[284]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
```

As a result, after a reboot, only one directory is mounted:

/home/r1ven/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand none bind 0 0

The second directory is not mounted and inaccessible.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong?)

When I mount the directory manually, everything works before the reboot and one directory is available from two FTP users, however, after the reboot, only the above directory is available, the second one is completely inaccessible, but if I manually mount it again, it will appear.

Answer (score 1):

You are making two bind mounts to the same destination mountpoint, on top of each other.

Step 1:

```
sudo mount --bind /home/max/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand
```

Now you will be able to access `/home/max/home/ExLand` at `/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand`.

Step 2: (assuming the `/etc/fstab` at the end of command is a typo)

```
sudo mount --bind /home/r1ven/home/ExLand /home/riven/Desktop/ExLand
```

This will make `/home/r1ven/home/ExLand` accessible at `/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand`, but the previous bind mount will no longer be accessible. (If you had existing sessions `cd`'d into `/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand`, they might still see the `/home/max/home/ExLand` version of it, but any new accesses will see the `/home/r1ven/home/ExLand` version only.)

If user `max` is making changes at `/home/max/home/ExLand`, user `r1ven` will never see those changes at `/home/r1ven/home/ExLand`, since they are still two separate locations.

The `systemd-fstab-generator` generates `.mount` unit names based on the destination mountpoint name, so two overlapping mount destinations like this would both have the same unit name, which is an error. Since overlapping mount points like this is not very useful and is usually a mistake, the error is probably a good thing.

If your goal is to have the users `max` and `r1ven` both access the `/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand`, you should do the bind mounts the opposite way.

Think of it like this: for `mount --bind`, the *source* is where the data *really* is; the *target* is where you want it to be seen.

So, `/etc/fstab` entries would be:

```
/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand /home/r1ven/home/ExLand none bind 0 0
/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand /home/max/home/ExLand none bind 0 0
```

After this, if `max` adds files to `/home/max/home/ExLand`, user `r1ven` will see them at `/home/r1ven/home/ExLand` too (assuming correct directory permissions)... because both of those locations are now actually accessing `/home/riven/Desktop/ExLand` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked!